# расположение текста html

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

как я могу задать расположение текста через PX (как картинку) к примеру width, hieght и тд. а не используя text-align. 
написал я очень криво, знаю, сам особо ничего не понимаю.
у меня правда текст отображается немного по другому, чем если выполнить код (в самом низу и по центру)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

body * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dance1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
}

.dance2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 1400px;
}

.logo {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 600px;
}

.test123 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: gold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=text">
<embed loop="true" src="" hidden="true"></embed>
<img class="dance1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=text1">
<img class="dance2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=text2">
<img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=text3">
<p class="test123">test 123</p>
```

Comment: мне нужно в верх его поставить

Comment: CSS: `font-size`, `margin`, `padding` думаю этого достаточно исходя из формулировки вопроса. в крайнем случае `position`.

Comment: Возможно, что вам нужно разобраться с понятием [Блочные и строчные элементы](https://html5book.ru/block-inline-elements/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Достаточно знать вот такую конструкцию

```
position: absolute; //положожение
top: 0;  //верх низ
left: 0;  //лево право
```

```css
#pertext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#pertext2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}

#pertext3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<p id="pertext">Привет мир!!!</p>

<p id="pertext2">Привет мир!!!</p>

<p id="pertext3">Привет мир!!!</p>
```

Comment: При значении 0 *px* не нужно указывать